# RHEL9.2 complains about missing /lib/modules/5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2.x86_64 when rebuilding initramfs

Tags: linux, lvm, linux-kernel, dracut, rhel9

The kernel on one of our RHEL9.2 servers was recently upgraded to 6.2.8 in preparation for a software upgrade but due to complications, we've had to revert back to 5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2.x86_64.

I've reinstalled the kernel packages using dnf via the following command

```bash
sudo dnf reinstall kernel-5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2 kernel-core-5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2 kernel-devel-5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2 kernel-headers-5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2 kernel-modules-5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2 kernel-modules-core-5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2 kernel-modules-extra-5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2
```

I understand that this in-itself will rebuild the initramfs for the kernel version, however after a reboot, I was dropped into a dracut emergency shell advising that

```bash
Warning: /dev/disk/by-id/md-uuid-582ae468:f4ec629b:79e6c251:fbba724a does not exist
Warning: /dev/mapper/vg_root-root does not exist
Warning: /dev/vg_root/root does not exist
Warning: /dev/vg_root/swap does not exist
```

It seems that no disks can be found. `blkid` returns nothing, and there are no disks in `/dev/` and the `/dev/disk` directory does not exist. Our root file system is on an LVM.

I can boot just fine into `5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_1.x86_64` and from here I attempted to rebuild the initramfs:

```bash
sudo dracut -f /boot/initramfs-5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2.x86_64.img 5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2.x86_64
```

which shows the following warnings:

```bash
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.order at /var/tmp/dracut.3hXitk/initramfs/lib/modules/5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2.x86_64: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open modules.builtin at /var/tmp/dracut.3hXitk/initramfs/lib/modules/5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2.x86_64: No such file or directory
```

`depmod -a` does not appear to resolve this.

Server model is `Cisco Systems Inc UCSC-C245-M6SX` if this changes anything